# Get URLs of taxonomies terms in Link field

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, navigation

I am having a link field in drupal 8. It can accept both internal and external links with autocomplete feature. But it works only with nodes means with content but i want to use it with taxonomy terms as well.

How can i achieve this ?
Any Help

Answer (score 0):

Nodes and taxonomies both use fields but they're stored slightly differently.  You will need to recreate your field for the taxonomy you wish to apply it to, it won't show up in `Use existing field`.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy terms can be inserted into "entity reference" fields which accepts both content/nodes as well as taxonomy term but not both at same time. You might get help with that one as it is an autocomplete field too.

> Go to "Add Field" tab in manage fields.
>
> Select under Reference -> Taxonomy Term.

Answer (score 0):

It is not (yet) possible. See issue on drupal.org for *link fields* for example in *menu link* or *redirect to*: [Allow multiple target entity types in the entity reference field](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2407587).

Comment: The referenced issue #2407587 is talking about solving this issue for for entity_autocomplete widget.  Its not clear if entity_autocomplete widget works with link fields, since link fields can support both external and internal links.

Comment: due to ^ I think https://www.drupal.org/i/2427803 is the correct issue to follow.

Comment: Issue #2427803 mentions another solution from https://drupal.org/i/2423093 which isn't ready for core, but supports multiple entity types. It relies on a patch, plus a sandbox for half-working mutli-entity autocomplete options: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/sam/2881047